# Running octave in Emacs

Tags: emacs, octave

I am using `run-octave` in Emacs to trigger `octave`. Something is acting abnormally.
Every time I hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> to complete, there would be a tailing `^M`; If I edit a `.m` file using `edit a.m`, it would start a new frame instead of a new buffer and the prompt is waiting for the closure of that frame so it would not respond to any input. How could I configure `.emacs` so that `run-octave` would behave normally?

Any comment is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have two problems. I'm not sure about the trailing `^M`, which seems to be caused by some sort of Windows/Unix CR/LF problem, but maybe I can help with the second problem.

The `edit` command uses the `EDITOR` environment variable to decide what to run. It seems that yours is either set to `emacsclient` or has defaulted to it. You haven't said whether you're on Unix or Windows, so I'm going to assume the former: you'll have to change this a bit for Windows.

To avoid the waiting thing, try running `octave` with a different `EDITOR`. For example, try out running

```
EDITOR='emacsclient -n' octave
```

When you type `edit foo`, it should bring up an Emacs buffer (if you want a new frame as well, use `-c` too) but not wait until you're done.

If this fixes things for you, you could change your `~/.bashrc` to include the line

```
export EDITOR='emacsclient -n'
```

Comment: Sure your method works fine when I start octave from the terminal; Thank u so much! however it fails when I use `M-x run-octave` from within emacs, where even if I set the EDITOR variable to 'emacsclient -n', using `edit a.m` will still start a new emacs frame. Any tip?

Comment: By the way, I am using Linux, and I set the variable in .emacs-octave. I also set it in .bashrc.

Comment: I'm not sure and I'm not at a computer where I can easily check, but you could try restarting Emacs or using `M-x setenv` to make sure that the EDITOR variable has been changed. Processes started via stuff like `M-x run-octave` inherit their environment from Emacs, so maybe that needs restarting? You can check Emacs's environment variables with `M-x getenv`. To restart Emacs, do it from a console in order to have reread `.bashrc` without having to log in & out.

Comment: What's strange is that I've set it in .bashrc and .emacs-octave, I can't see it using `M-x getenv`,when starting octave from within emacs using `M-x run-octave`, EDITOR in the octave prompt echos `emacsclient -n`. So the answer may be emacs don't know I've set the varible in .bashrc or .emacs-octave. Finally, I set the it by put `(setenv "EDITOR" "emacsclient -n")` in .emacs and it works. Thank you for all your help!